# How to optimize Android widgets for both phone and tablet?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to have 3x1 widget. It works perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S3 but on my tablet the same widget only shows ~%80 of my widget.. I don't want do define it as 3x2 because it will have empty space on tablet and more empty space on Galaxy S3.

How can I optimize this widget for both devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different layouts for phone and tablet
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"

Put phone layout to layout/widget_layout.xml and tablet to layout-sw480dp/widget_layout.xml